# Samba file cannot be delete when samba is mounted as network drive

Tags: networking, mount, network-shares, samba

I have a samba folder mounted as a Z: drive on Windows. When this is done, no files can be created or deleted on the samba drive, even if it is owned by the user who mounted the drive.

If I am just connecting through the network section of windows, the user can delete files, whether or not they own them. This is what I want in both cases. How would I get that to work.

Edit 1: after some thinking, I am now wondering if it is no longer logging the user as logged in when mounted this way, could this be it?

Comment: Post your smb.conf file, usually located at "/etc/samba/smb.conf" Also, if you're not concerned about security, you can create a public share so anyone with access to your network can access the share and make changes. Otherwise, you will need to "create" a samba account and configure your share to use that account for authentication when trying to connect to the share.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson I forgot to post here. I figured out the solution and I am going to post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to have figured it out. The shared folder was not marked as writable by the user who was accessing it over the network share.